# I want to pre-populate a form with a foreign key. I click an add link against supplier and add a review without retyping the supplier

Tags: django

I want to click a link next to the supplier and add a review. I should not be required to retype or select the supplier but just enter review details. However I get an error of MultiValueDictKeyError 
'supplier.pk'.  The error occurs in the get_initial method and specifically supplier.pk. The form is not opened in this case

the title bare shows /review/add/2/ which implies that the supplier id 2 is available

I also tried this code which opened the form (has other review fields but not supplier field). I got the error  KeyError at /comment/add/5/ 'supplier'

```
''' I got the error  KeyError at /comment/add/5/ 'supplier' with code 
below '''
class CreateReview(FormView):
    form_class = AddReviewForm
    template_name = 'comment_new.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy ('supplier_reviews')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        supplier = get_object_or_404(Supplier, 
             slug=self.kwargs['supplier']) 
        form.instance.supplier = supplier 
        return super(CreateReview,self).form_valid(form)
```

The link below starts of the process
     Add a review

code of my models and view are provided below

```
class Supplier(models.Model): 
    """Model representing suppliers.""" 
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_n01 = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    contact_n02 = models.CharField(max_length=15)


class Review(models.Model): 
    """Model representing members.""" 
    date = models.DateField()
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
         null=True)

class CreateReview(FormView):
    form_class = AddReviewForm
    template_name = 'comment_new.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy ('supplier_details')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(CreateReview,self).form_valid(form)

    ''' I get an error of MultiValueDictKeyError 'supplier.pk' from below 
        code  '''
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = {}
        params = self.request.GET
        supplier = Supplier.objects.get(id=params['supplier.pk'])
        initial['supplier'] = supplier
        return initial
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed from FormView to CreateView and introduced model and dropped form_class

```
class CreateReview(CreateView):
    model = Rating
    template_name = 'comment_new.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy ('supplier_list') 


    def form_valid(self, form):
        supplier = Supplier.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        form.instance.supplier = supplier
        return super(CreateReview,self).form_valid(form)
```